# How to make clang-format not break after = signs and not BinPackArguments

Tags: c++, llvm, code-formatting, clang-format

I'm using clang-format with a small configuration file, based on the Microsoft style.

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
BinPackParameters: 'false'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
ColumnLimit: '120'
#Other options...
...
```

Consider this piece of unformatted code:

```
    ClassObj = new ClassName(status, pixel_selection, options, error, argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5);
```

My desired result is to have no break after the equal sign, & BinPackArguments = 'false', like the following:

```
    ClassObj = new ClassName(status, 
                             pixel_selection, 
                             options, 
                             error, 
                             argument1, 
                             argument2, 
                             argument3, 
                             argument4, 
                             argument5);
```

---

Using clang-format with previous mentioned configuration I get:

```
    ClassObj =
        new ClassName(status, pixel_selection, options, error, argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5);
```

---

Further adding:

```
PenaltyBreakAssignment: '21'
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: '1'
```

I get:

```
    ClassObj = new ClassName(
        status, pixel_selection, options, error, argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5);
```

---

Is it possible to get the desired result, based on the Microsoft style?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlignAfterOpenBracket` for some additional control:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
BinPackParameters: 'false'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
AlignAfterOpenBracket: 'Align'
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: 'false'
ColumnLimit: '120'
#Other options...
...
```

However this will result in your requested formatting only if all arguments to not fit on a single second line withing the column limit. For you example and with column limit 120, without additional indent this will not be the case.

One would think that `AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine` as `false` would fix this, but it seems not to be respected even after tweaking `PenaltyBreakAssignment` and `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter` as you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think we are at the strange case where

`new ClassName(status, pixel_selection, options, error, argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5);` 
is less than 120 characters long.

If the line is longer (eg more parameters) I get the desired behavior, even with the default Microsoft style values for `AlignAfterOpenBracket` and `AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine`.

I will keep looking and hopefully there is a clang-format option that can tackle this case..